# JFrame size should reduce the maximum available size for the desktop

Tags: java, swing, jframe, size

I am in need to create an application that is always in the foreground. The application itself should be interface. After I made it stay in the foreground with:

```
this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

In the next step, as it is an user interface, I'd like the JFrame to reduce the the available size for the rest of the desktop. A little example: The screen has got a width of 1024 pixels. The interface has got a width of 324 pixels. The size being left for the desktop and it´s applications (mainly the applications) shoild lower to a maximum of 700 pixel.

Is there a way to create such a behavior in Java?

Comment: What?  Are you saying that if (for example) the frame is on the far left of my screen, it pushes all the desktop icons to the right?  I bloody hope not!

Comment: No, just a little different. The desktop itself should stay on the same size. But all the applications should resize themself to not lay behind the interface.

Comment: Again 'yuck' & I hope not.  I imagine it would require natives.

Answer (score 0):

A pure Java application has no access to windows created by other applications, so you would need some platform-dependent "native" C code, if you want to control this functionality from a Java app.

An alternative (on Windows only) would be to write an AutoHotkey script that is started independently from your Java app, and keeps resizing the other windows.

Answer (score 0):

Test this code:

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds()// no status bar
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();// with status bar
myFrame.setUndecorated(true);// clear frame's titlebar and border
```